# Finding index of clicked element in WPF GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have a GridView of elements, I want to perform some operations when one of the elements is clicked. So I set `ItemClick` property of the GridView to `TopicsPage_ItemClick` and implement the method. I tried to react like this (a few of attempts):

```
private void TopicsPage_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    int index = itemGridView.SelectedIndex;
    string topicName = this.topicList[index].Name;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CardsPage), topicName);
}

private void TopicsPage_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    int index = itemGridView.Items.IndexOf((e.ClickedItem as FrameworkElement));
    string topicName = this.topicList[index].Name;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CardsPage), topicName);
}

private void TopicsPage_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    int index = itemGridView.Items.IndexOf(item);
    string topicName = this.topicList[index].Name;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CardsPage), topicName);
}
```

But every solution above throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with `index = -1`. I have exactly the same solution on another page, where I have buttons in GridView and implement `Click` of them, and it works there. Any advice would be apprecitated.

Comment: not sure what are you bindings, but you can have a look at my article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele) about selected index/value, etc. What's the difference between this and your other? only the type of element?

Comment: I'm not sure about the GridView in Windows Phone, but I guess the `e.ClickedItem as FrameworkElement` will evaluate to `null`. Try passing the `ClickedItem` directly like this `itemGridView.Items.IndexOf(e.ClickedItem)`

Comment: The first snippet does not work maybe because the `SelectedIndex` has not been determined at the time of clicking. For the third snippet, I think there is some Binding related issue here. Just try the second snippet with my suggestion above.

Comment: Should really tag this as WP8.1.  There is no such thing as GridView on WP8.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware I don't know about Windows Phone, next time you can edit the Tag yourself.

Comment: @KingKing I only saw the tags.  Not even sure, if he's doing a Windows Phone project since WPF is also tag.  Someone must of added those extra tags by accident.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware well in `WPF` desktop, the `GridView` does not have any `ItemClick` event, so I guessed it's Windows Phone, searching also showed that it just exists in Windows Phone but I did not notice about the exact version.

Comment: Guys not sure why you added :Windows Phone" tags, it was not about WP. Anyway it appears the "as" cast was indeed returning null, Chubosaurus' answer works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gonna assume your GridView ItemsSource is bind to a collection.

Here are the behaviors from my experience if you have `IsItemClickEnabled="True"` the `ItemClick` event will fire BUT the `SelectionChanged` will not fire leaving you with the SelectedIndex of -1.

To get the index you can you grab it by casting it from the IndexOf

```
private void TopicsPage_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;
    index = gv.Items.IndexOf(e.ClickedItem);   // don't re cast it as anything; just past it
}
```

You can also get it from the GridView.ItemsSource collection.IndexOf as well if you like